# return multiple elements in array.map / Subcategories in dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using array.map to loop through a nested array.
indicatorCategories is my first array which contains a name and id, and an nested array named indicators.

I'm mapping these indicators to a dropdown in react-bootstrap, but I also have to map the name of the category.

Currently this is the code I have.

```
{indicatorCategories.map(indicatorCategory => {
            return (
              (
                <option
                  disabled
                  key={indicatorCategory.id}
                  value={indicatorCategory.id}
                >
                  {"---" + indicatorCategory.name + "---"}
                </option>
              ),
              indicatorCategory.indicators.map(indicator => {
                return (
                  <option key={indicator.id} value={indicator.id}>
                    {indicator.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })
            );
          })}
```

The result is that I'm only mapping the indicators, the indicatorCategories do not show up. I guess array.map isn't ment to return an element and map over a nested array? Or am I just making a stupid syntax error? Been wrestling with it for a while but no cigar.

If it's not possible, what are the alternatives here? I prefer not using some hover over categories to show the indicators from that category since it isn't very mobile friendly.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a flatMap method (which is not native in js). Take a look at what's happening here : 

JS flatMap example : https://gist.github.com/samgiles/762ee337dff48623e729 . Difference between map and flatMap : 
http://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap

Comment: simplified, you're returning something like `(a, [b, c, d])`, which evaluates to just `[b, c, d]`. Try with `[a, [b, c, d]]` instead. In other words, replace `return (...)` with `return [...]`;

Comment: Not very clear on what is the issue here. Your code generates exactly what it should.
Can you clarify the end-goal? A list of selcect boxes? A select box that shows industryCategories, that when you select an industryCategory it shows the indicators as an option?

Comment: @xs0, this solves my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need to do with a combination of `reduce` and `map`. Here's an example with dummy data, you transfer it to react.

```
let data = [
    {
    id: 1, 
    value: 'a',
    data: [
      {id: 11, value: 'b'}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    value: 'aa',
    data: [
      {id: 12, value: 'bb'},
      {id: 12, value: 'bb'},
    ]
  }
]


let results = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc = acc.concat(cur.value);

  return acc.concat(
    cur.data.map((nested) => {
        return nested.value;
    })
  )
}, []);

console.log(results)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avLvxsb6/

As you can see in results you have all the values from the array and the nested arrays. Another alternative is to map the data and then flatten the results so you don't have nested arrays. Then you loop through that and render

Comment: This would also work!
what xs0 proved is a bit easier in this case since the number element in the nested array may vary and the category needs to be unclickable.

I'll select this as the accepted answer because I can't accept comments.

Thanks to you both, array.reduce is something I should remember :).